# How can I set a URL for a blank tab without loading the page?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm developing a Firefox extension that uses an online source code viewer tool as a proxy to download a blocked web page, It then injects the page's HTML code into a blank tab.

It works as expected so far but the problem is the new tab doesn't have a URL associated with it so all the relative paths set for links, images, style-sheets, and other resources won't point to real paths any more.

I've tried `history.pushState()` and `history.replaceState()` but they work only if the new URL is of the same origin as the current URL, while the new tab doesn't have a URL at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element, which

> specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document.

You can create it with `var base = document.createElement('base');` then, after you appended it to the `<head>` of the document, you can specify the baseURI of the document using its `href` attribute : `base.href= yourDocURI;`

```js
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
// set a relative path to it
anchor.href = '../../someDoc.html';

// create a new document
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('empty page');
// append our anchor to the about:blank doc
doc.body.appendChild(anchor);

snippet.log('without base : '+ anchor.href);

var base = document.createElement('base');
base.href = "http://example.com/some/folder/index.html";
doc.head.appendChild(base);

snippet.log('with base : '+ anchor.href);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```